# unable to child autowire bean in abstract parent class

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, spring-aop

```
abstract class Parent {
 private Parent self;
 private ParentMember parentMember;
 
 
 @MyAspect
 private void functionality() {
   //some functionality
 }
}

@Component
class Child1 extends Parent {
 @Autowire
 private ChildMember childMember;
}
```

Restrictions -

1. There are more than 50 classes implementing Parent. And I dont want to make changes to them.
2. I have to add some functionality in parent now in legacy code. And for that I need to self inject the child bean into parent to access the inner method call functionality via spring AOP.
3. Another issue is the parent class is in a library where spring is not a dependency so spring annotations like @Autowire, etc are not available.
4. I can create abstract class parent bean in xml probably in the service where child class is defined.
5. Child class beans are created using component scan in a package. So, these child classes dont have any beans defined in XML.

With so much restrictions, do we have a way to inject the created child bean into parent post construction of bean? I don't think this is possible now.

Comment: The question looks interesting, but is a bit too abstract for my taste. I cannot debug prose, only code, and I am not sure I really 100% understand all the subtleties of your situation after only reading your explanation. The best you can do in order to get help here is to condense your application into a small, but complete sample application, an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and publishing it on GitHub after anonymising it.

Comment: Looks like the question was not so important, after all. So if it has become irrelevant for you now, please just delete it, before someone else has to read it and maybe even tries answering to an unresponsive original poster.